# The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to

Tags: c#, constructor, properties, getter-setter

In *Constructor* **Day** has problem:

> The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to.

But in the same case for **Month** in *Constructor* it works. Why?

```
struct Date
{
    private byte day;

    public byte Day
    {
        get { return day; }
        set {
            if (value > 0 && value < 32)
                day = value;
            else
                day = 0;
        }
    }

    private byte month;

    public byte Month
    {
        get { return month; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && value < 13)
                month = value;
            else
                month = 0;
        }
    }

    public Date(byte day, byte month)
    {
        Day = day;
        Month = month;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.day = day; this.month = month;`. You're setting the Property, not the backing Field. The error applies to `Day = day;` (before the struct fields are initialized), not to the use of `this`.

Comment: No it doesn't, try removing the line causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, the compiler is just stopping after the first error.  If you comment out `Day = day` you'll see the same error on `Month = month`.

(Tested with dotnetfiddle/.NET 4.7.2, I suppose other compilers may be different.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help. 
I have found solution.
I tried to change **struct** to **class** for *Date*. It worked.

```
class Date
```

{

}

Comment: Yes, this works! But why is this?